# Is a dynamically sized heap insertion technically O(n)?

Tags: data-structures, heap

Inserting an element into a heap involves appending it to the end of the array and then propagating it upwards until it's in the "right spot" and satisfies the heap property, the operation of which is O(logn).

However, in C, for instance, calling `realloc` in order to resize the array for the new element can (and likely will) result in having to copy the entirety of the array to another location in memory, which is O(n) in the best and worst case, right?

Are heaps in C (or any language, for that matter) usually done with a fixed, pre-allocated size, or is the copy operation inconsequential enough to make a dynamically sized heap a viable choice (e.g, a binary heap to keep a quickly searchable list of items)?

Comment: Big O describes the overall scalability of an algorithm, NOT the nitty-gritty specifics like the implementation details of `realloc`. Don't take it as gospel truth, just as a metric for comparison to other algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical scheme is to double the size when you run out of room.  This doubling--and the copying that goes with it--does indeed take O(n) time.

However, notice that you don't have to perform this doubling very often.  If you average out the total cost of all the doubling over all the operations performed on the heap that did not involve doubling, then the cost is indeed inconsequential.  (This kind of averaging is known as [amortized analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis).)